# The Princeton University Bicentennial Conference on the Problems of Mathematics

Tags: soft-question

In 1946 a conference was held at Princeton University on the occasion of its 250th anniversary. The conference was extraordinary, as it was attended by many prominent mathematicians of the time, including von Neumann, Hermann Weyl, etc. I want to know whether there exist any proceedings containing the papers presented at the event.

The only source I found is a report published in volume 2 of the book A century of mathematics in America (edited by Peter Duren) that seems to be a reprint of the book Problems of Mathematics. It contains a brief summary of the event, and not the whole paper.

Any additional information or references would be appreciated.

__, Problems of Mathematics, (Princeton University Bicentennial Conferences, Ser. II. Conference 2) Princeton, N. J.: Princeton University 32 p. (1947). [ZBL0063.06345](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.06345).

Comment: https://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/math-history/hmath2-princeton-2.pdf

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting read! Great names falling like confetti.

Comment: @Paul: I looked out of curiosity, and then did a quick count (total might be off by 1 or 2) -- 82 names at the end, and I didn't immediately recognize only 11 of them (Ancohea, Bohnenblust, Cairns, Chiang, Harrold, Hedlund, Hotelling, Hua, Murnaghan, Thomas, Walker).

Comment: I recognize Hedlund, Hotelling and Hua. Pretty intimidating meeting!

Comment: I am striken by the fact that the list of participants displays but a handful of non-US mathematicians. In particular not a single  French mathematician.

Comment: @Jean Marie it was 1946 and it was in the US, so that might go a long way to explain US based mathematicians

Comment: @Paul thanks. I understand from your previous comment there was at least an italian mathematician "Great names falling like Confetti".

Comment: @Prem Thanks! This is exactly the chapter in "A century of mathematics in America"

Comment: The attendees of the event were extremely great mathematicians. You might be interested to look at the following link that contains a conference photo:
https://albert.ias.edu/handle/20.500.12111/4685